# Is it a good practice to embed mappings for errorcodes inside JSON?

Tags: xml, json, transformation

Have a glance at [this snippet](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37403003@N08/3612570579/) of JSON.

**Motivation**: The JSON is generated by a REST service & later on will be
converted to XML.

**Simple Question**: I am currently embedding the map for the error codes inside the JSON snippet, with the intention of helping the transformation to XML. The XML format does not use numeric codes. Should I place the mapping inside the JSON or inside the code that will do the transformation?

Comment: Sharing code snippets via Flickr??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of it as a map think of it as an enumerator.
Now it make more sense to put both value and its numeric value in the json.

Comment: Would you have done the same if you're designing a JSON structure of the same ilk ?